# Settle an argument {by, amongst} yourselves?

Tags: prepositions

**Sentence:**

> You, boys, must settle it __ yourselves

**Problem:** Fill in the blank with an appropriate preposition.

**Attempt:** I am thinking of "by". My friend is thinking of "amongst". I suggest "by" because that means that those boys have to settle their dispute on their own. He suggested "amongst" because they are a group so they can divide or share the settling amongst themselves.

**Question:** Which answer is correct and why? Thanks!

Comment: If there are two boys, then use _between_. If there are three or more, use _among_ or _amongst_.

Comment: I was thinking on *settle it on*, which it's just *agree*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the following are correct and would all communicate *essentially* the same meaning: The boys need to settle it and will not receive assistance in doing so. (Alternatively, the speaker might intend to communicate *If it's going to be settled at all, you'll need to do it yourselves.*)

The only exception is that *among* or *amongst* would generally not be chosen if only two boys are being addressed.

Not all good or educated writers and language experts agree with the commonly-held idea that *between* cannot properly be used to indicate relationship between(!) more than two people. See below.

*Amongst* is more frequently used in British English than in American English, in which *among* is preferred between the two.

- You, boys, must settle it between yourselves.
- You, boys, must settle it among yourselves.
- You, boys, must settle it amongst yourselves.
- You, boys, must settle it for yourselves.
- You, boys, must settle it by yourselves.
- You, boys, must settle it yourselves. (No preposition is needed.)

Regarding *between, among, and amongst,* see the usage note at [*between*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=B5220200) in The American Heritage Dictionary.

Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among. I particularly recommend @tchrist's thorough treatment of this question in his answer there.

*The six options were identified by @snailboat in an ELL chatroom. But all elaboration on them is mine. Thanks, snailboat!*

Comment: 'Settle it *for* yourselves' is what popped into my mind upon seeing the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I think *'among'* is the better option. As he said, *'you'* isn't referred to you alone, per se. Here, *'you'* means *'the boys'*. So, it is  a group. And in such cases, *'among'* or *'amongst'* is the best option. The use of *'by'* wouldn't be wrong if *'yourselves'* were *'yourself'*. But it's not. Among the two, I would go with *'among'*.

> You, boys, must settle it **amongst/ among** yourselves.

and

> You must settle it **by** yourself.

**Note**: Consider this sentence :

> "Despite of what they were told, they decided to go there **by** themselves."

In many cases, "by" can be used instead of "among". But in cases which involves a solution for something between the individuals, *'among'* or *'amongst'* is used - 
*"They sorted their differences among themselves."*.

Comment: I don't think _by yourselves_ is necessarily wrong; it can mean "without any outside help." Consider: "Dad, can you help us put together this jigsaw puzzle?" "No, I can't right now – you'll have to put it together by yourselves."

Comment: Not if it's a sister and two brothers working collaboratively on the puzzle. Had my original question been: "Consider: "Dad, can you help **me** put together this jigsaw puzzle?" then "...by yourself" would be appropriate.

Comment: Using the preposition **by** has nothing to do with its object being singular or plural. Your last sentence is not clear. Does it mean *they decided to go there without anyone accompanying them* or *they decided to go there without anyone influencing their decision*? You need to clarify this point. Please edit your post and I will reverse my downvote.